# Laravel Session::getId() returns multiple IDs

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm trying to explore a bit more in-depth how sessions work in Laravel. I have added a middleware to my application that simply outputs the current session ID to the log:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
  Log::debug('My session id is ' . \Session::getId());
  return $next($request);
}
```

To my great surprise, every time I load a page, I get several different session IDs:

```
[2019-04-02 03:38:28] local.DEBUG: My session id is TthZevtJ9iwoQToZKRJq44Z5n2t1Bo09kJAK2nK8  
[2019-04-02 03:38:28] local.DEBUG: My session id is LMF6zX54XzbEgRVLVTZLDZXmrOVPVWQyoosPQJEH  
[2019-04-02 03:38:30] local.DEBUG: My session id is YyBkGQs83NhGrfFkfUV2qSbFcYovTsptctytwlbM  
[2019-04-02 03:38:30] local.DEBUG: My session id is HPoT79VqgONl03NFZKjSDto10NlAoMArbxSIKzAq  
[2019-04-02 03:38:31] local.DEBUG: My session id is LMF6zX54XzbEgRVLVTZLDZXmrOVPVWQyoosPQJEH
```

I don't understand why there seem to be different sessions for the loading of one page - and which session I would need to destroy if I wanted to disconnect the user for instance

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner or browser extension that might be doing some page pre-loading?

Comment: I have an antivirus and some browsers extensions indeed but how could these create their "own" session without me providing them with credentials?

Comment: Some AV scan the pages you visit for links which it follows to pre-scan further. These would all be separate sessions to the one in your browser.

Comment: Thanks - I tried in a browser with extensions disabled and antivirus disabled but still getting these "parasite" session IDs

Comment: So you only get them when you visit a page? Check your browser's _Network_ console for any requests that would go through your middleware

Comment: Whenever I visit a page or send a request (ajax for instance) to the server. I tested with a simple polling "GET" request sent to the server, the Network console shows that only one requete is sent, yet I get two session IDs: the first one changes with every request, the second one is always the same (and seems to be the "real" session ID)

Comment: Are they cross-origin requests?

Comment: This is not cross-origin strictly speaking as it's client.domain.com requesting client.domain.com, but I continued looking and it looks like sessions can behave a bit strangely when subdomains are involved.. my session cookie domain is set to ".domain.com" to be available through all subdomains